# NSMutableDictionary рассчитать расстояние до маркера

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Подскажите, просто не знаю в сторону каких функций копать, вот есть такой словарик

```
        states = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
   [states setObject:@"60.050043,30.345783" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km", (betweenDistance / 1000)] ];
   [states setObject:@"60.037389,30.322094" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km", (betweenDistance4 / 1000)] ];
    [states setObject:@"60.037329,30.322014" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km", (betweenDistance5 / 1000)] ];
   [states setObject:@"59.957387,30.324681" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km", (betweenDistance3 / 1000)] ];
     datasource = [states allKeys];
```

если вкрации - словарь выводится в tableview, там при нажатии открывается detailview с картой гугла на которой отражаются маркер. Координаты маркера это Object в словаре.В tableview выводится key (т.е. расстояние до маркера). Т.е. (betweenDistance3 / 1000) переменная которая образовывается из `float betweenDistance5=[startLocation distanceFromLocation:location5];` а эта переменная образуется из `CLLocation *location5 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:60.037329 longitude:30.322014];`. И вот собственно вопрос как мне в tableview вывести cell от меньшего расстояния к большему? Можно ли это сделать как то в словаре? (переменные наверно нет смысла перебирать, потому что идёт жесткая привязка объект - ключ (т.е. определённые координаты соответствуют определённое переменной `(betweenDistance3 / 1000)`))

**UPDATE**

```
     [states setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km", (betweenDistance5 / 1000)] forKey:@"60.037329,30.322014" ];
 [states setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km", (betweenDistance3 / 1000)] forKey:@"59.957387,30.324681" ];
 datasource = [states allValues];
NSArray* sortedStates = [states keysSortedByValueUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2)
{
    if ([obj1 floatValue] < [obj2 floatValue])
    {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    if ([obj1 floatValue] > [obj2 floatValue])
    {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }

    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];

  [states setObject:@"60.050043,30.345783" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km", (betweenDistance / 1000)] ];
[states setObject:@"60.037389,30.322094" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km", (betweenDistance4 / 1000)] ];
 [states setObject:@"60.037329,30.322014" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km", (betweenDistance5 / 1000)] ];
 [states setObject:@"59.957387,30.324681" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km", (betweenDistance3 / 1000)] ];
 datasource = [states allKeys];
NSArray* sortedStates = [states keysSortedByValueUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2)
{
    if ([obj1 floatValue] < [obj2 floatValue])
    {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    if ([obj1 floatValue] > [obj2 floatValue])
    {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }

    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Comment: В вашем коде есть возможный баг, когда, например, betweenDistance4 окажется случайно равен betweenDistance. Тогда ключ будет такой же, какой уже есть в словаре и запись перепишется вместо добавления новой. Возможно, словарь здесь вообще не подходит и если решать задачу по-другому, то отсортировать окажется легче.

Comment: Anastasia бес словаря тут тоже сложно - идёт связка ключ значение по которой открывается карта

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы избежать бага, описанного в комментарии, можно использовать словарь, только нужно поменять в нем ключ со значением. Тогда ключом будет координата, а значением - расстояние. Из этого словаря можно получить массив ключей (координат), отсортированных по значению (расстоянию).

```
NSMutableDictionary* states = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[states setObject: @(betweenDistance / 1000) forKey:@"60.050043,30.345783"];
[states setObject: @(betweenDistance4 / 1000) forKey:@"60.037389,30.322094"];
[states setObject: @(betweenDistance5 / 1000) forKey:@"60.037329,30.322014"];
[states setObject: @(betweenDistance3 / 1000) forKey:@"59.957387,30.324681"];

NSArray* sortedStates = [states keysSortedByValueUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2)
{
    if ([obj1 floatValue] > [obj2 floatValue])
    {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    if ([obj1 floatValue] < [obj2 floatValue])
    {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }

    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

UPDATE:

Строки таблицы:

```
NSMutableArray* rows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString* key in sortedStates)
    {
        CGFloat distance = [[states objectForKey:key] floatValue];
        [rows addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km", distance]];
    }
```

При выборе строки вызывается метод

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString* coord = sortedStates[indexPath.row];
}
```

Эту `coord` можно передать дальше.

Comment: я так понимаю на выходе у нас получается массив?

Comment: Да, массив координат, отсортированный по расстоянию.

Comment: @ Anastasia подскажите а если я не буду переделывать словарь как у вас в примере, то мне достаточно floatValue заменить на forKey и тоже будет работать?

Comment: смотрите, в вопросе добавил оба моих варианта, не один не работает

Comment: Оба ваши варианта не работают потому, что массив сортируется исходя из того, что он содержит объекты типа float (точнее, NSNumber из float), а у вас в обоих случаях строка. Почему вам нужен словарь именно в таком виде (со строкой "Distance is %f km")?

Comment: @AnastasiaМожно и без строки, просто там должно выводится расстояние (в вашем когде выводились пустые строки), и ещё момент, почему я взял словарь- там идёт пара- расстояние координаты, и координаты соответствуют расстоянию, и при нажатии на cell координаты передаются в другую view на карте, и ставится маркер в соответствии с этими координатами. А если просто будет массив как мне передать соответствующие координаты?

Comment: @ГошкаТарасов: То, что выводится неправильно — проблема выводящего кода. Вам сначала нужно сделать правильную логику программы, то есть формировать правильные данные, а только потом дописывать вокруг этого логику вывода. Для передачи данных в другую view надо сформировать эти данные, это не имеет отношения к данной проблеме.

Comment: @Anastasia вот смотрите, я пытаюсь передать coord из одного файла в другой, но ничего не выходит, вроде же всё правильно сделал... http://cl.ly/3S1t2o2m0r0g?_ga=1.166352312.701167339.1426154549